# Spanning a RadioButtonList over 6 DIVS

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Question about the `<asp:RadioButtonList>` class. I have a 2 row, 3 column DIV setup with Radio Button options like this:

```
() Option 1  |  () Option 2 | () Option 3
-----------------------------------------
() Option 4  |  () Option 5 | () Option 6
```

Reason being is that when users select different options additional info will be displayed via  jQuery but I want all the options tied to 1 list so that when Option 1 is selected nothing else is and when Option 5 is selected it deselects Option 1. Basic RadioButtonList type of stuff.

Alas from what I've read/hacked is that with the asp:RBL class you can't enter any html or other code between the  tags.

Any thoughts on how to do this? If I keep the ID the same it errors out saying that list already exists...

Thanks for any pointers.

Edit:

I believe I found the solution. Instead of using a RadioButtonList I just used RadioButton and implemented the GroupName option to bind them together. Looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

- use multiple RadioButtons with the GroupName attribute (as you mentioned)
- manipulate them later with JavaScript if you really want to keep using the RadioButtonList
- use HTML radio buttons and bind them manually

I suggest the first option as it is the simplest balance of robustness, power, and simplicity.